# Call a trigger function after page got refreshed/reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a anchor tag in one page on click am redirecting to other page. Once page got refreshed , i want to call a trigger function which is present in current page.
Tried with below code.

```
$('#id').click(function() {

  $('.class').trigger('click'); // class present in other page

});
```

Kindly help me.

Comment: you need to make sure new page also have this code and #id element

Comment: Code in first page can't do anything on second page. They each load their own script(s).

Comment: What you could do is pass a specific `GET` parameter to the second page, and then check for the presence of this parameter on the second page's page load.

Comment: is there any way to use a flag , if true can i call a trigger function?

Comment: sessionStorage/localStorage could also be used for that purpose.

Comment: but if i use session/localstorage , each time i refresh page , trigger will get called. I need to call only if i click that button @Taplar

Comment: Once you use it you'd unset that variable

Comment: I have done with localstorage.. just want to know will it cause any problem in future @Taplar. so which is best? handling with query parameters or local storage?

Comment: So long as you clear it after you use it, it shouldn't be a problem.  Doing so would result in F5 not repeating the action, where as with a query param F5 would definitely repeat the action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a query to the page you open, an example you be:

Assuming you have an `index.html` that has a link to other `page.html`:

```
<a href="page.html?flag=true">Open Page</a>
```

Then in `page.html`:

```
function getQueryStringValue (key) {  
  return decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + encodeURIComponent(key).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));  
} 
if (getQueryStringValue('flag') === 'true') {
  // do what you need
};
```